# Configuring Hue to point to a HDInsight HDP cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hue, azure-hdinsight

I have downloaded the source code of Hue and have built it locally on my Ubuntu (16.04) system. I want to configure it to point to my HDInsight HDP cluster head-node so that I can access my hive databases. I am aware of the script action, but want the Hue on remote system and point it to the cluster. How can I go about?

Comment: please share some more details on what you have tried so far.  have you tried [cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_sg_hiveserver2_security.html#topic_9_1_3_unique_1)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am using HDP. I have tried to configure Hue as given in [link](http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/). The Hue portal is working on localhost:8000 but I am unable to see any of my hive databases.

Comment: Make sure your hive is running and make sure that you have configured hue.ini properly. try to check for errors in logs